# PHP form & .htaccess conflict

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a couple simple contact forms on my page. 
All was working well (form was sent to the email in the script) until I added this .htaccess file.

Is there a way to process the php form while also including the .htaccess file?
(because it made the site look really nice)

Thanks in advance.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

FORM CODE:

```
<?php
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$from = 'From: Contact Page';
$to = 'xxxx@xxx.com';
$subject = 'Contact Page';
$human = $_POST['human'];

$body = "From: $first_name\n $last_name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {

    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        header('Location: http://www.xxxxxx.com/ThankYou.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        header('Location: http://www.xxxxxx.com/error.php');
    }
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
    header('Location: http://www.xxxxxx.com/error.php');;
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the action of the form? why you add a server config without knowing what you do?

Comment: Can you add the form code?

Comment: the form is posting.  I added it because I knew what I "wanted" it to do ;)..  (That was to make the url's nice.) If I always knew what I was doing, I'd never do anything ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable `POST` method from first redirect rule since external redirect will not carry `POST` data to new URL. Use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

btw this full `.htaccess` smells like one of my old answers on SO :)

Comment: This definitely could be your script :).  And if so, thank you for posting it the first time and thank you for the update. You helped me out immensely.

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: Is there a reason why my emails won't go through?

Comment: email not going through can have many reasons. I suggest opening a new question with all relevant details and we'll try to help you.